# PHP: $_GET is unable to fetch the URL query parameters

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch the URL query parameters using `$_GET` method like below:

```
URL: www.xyz.com?pagewanted=2

$pagewanted = $_GET["pagewanted"];

echo "value of pagewanted is:" . $pagewanted;
```

OutPut: value of pagewanted is:

Not able to get the value of Query param pagewanted. What could be issue? Is it any server issue?

Comment: _Is it any server issue?_ . You can tell us including at the top of your file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check if there is any error in it.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`, see if that parameter ever made it to PHP.

Comment: Are you doing this in your index.php file? if yes, try url `www.xyz.com/index.php?pagewanted=2`

Comment: Do you have any type of url rewriting set up in your webserver

Comment: $_GET is a global variable and can be overridden, search all of you code to see if you are setting $_GET to anything else.

Comment: i tried var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']). It is Null.